# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Account_

Tags: json, entity-framework, automapper

i'm just new to ASP.NET and other things with it.. i am using automapper in entity framework which is giving the ERROR.......
this occurs when i tried to get the desired data with JSON response...

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Account_C2A5EBE3CC4467F8B34569FAEB8687C41333F5D82DB38AC1D2E21FC5F8A47193'.]

i have tried many resources on stackoverflow and on other platforms also but there is no solid solution to this problem.
i have turned on LAZY LOADING using virtual keyword in MODELS.
i don't want to turn off lazy loading using ..

> Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

i am searching for the other solution to load all the data using the lazy loading ..

If i am going to off lazy loading then other headaches are to face on.

please help me out Seniors ...........

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Do not serialize the entire entity. Instead, convert it to a more simple class, and then serialize that object. I recommend you to use AutoMapper for object conversion.
2. If you use Json.Net, you can add the JsonIgnore attribute on top of the properties you want to avoid.

My recommendation is the first option. I think is a good idea to return only the objects you really need. For that purpose, you should have simple model objects and a mapper that transforms between your entities and this model classes. If, for example, all your entity objects are completely connected, there can be the case that you will serialize the entire database, which is not desirable. Try to move out the Entities from the presentation layer.